ActiveMQ Artemis broker connection to ActiveMQ Classic
I'm trying to configure an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.33 in order to connect with another broker AMQP, an instance of ActiveMQ Classic 5.15.
The goal is to receive messages in Artemis from one topic destination (i.e. topic "test") defined on AMQ Classic.
Here is the tested configuration on Artemis instance:
 <broker-connections>
      <amqp-connection uri="tcp://amq_classic_host:5673" name="activemq-classic" retry-interval="1000" reconnect-attempts="2" user="***" password="***">
            <receiver address-match="test"/>
      </amqp-connection>
 </broker-connections>

The address "test" is predefined as multicast on Artemis:
  <address name="test">
      <multicast/>
  </address>

and "test" is also a topic destination on Classic:
<destinations>
  ...
  <topic physicalName="test" />
</destinations>

On startup Artemis will connect correctly to Classic but attached to a destination "test" of "queue" type.
Tried also to prefix "topic://" in the "address-match" property but in this case no consumer is instantiated on Classic side.
Someone has any idea how to connect Artemis to Classic and subscribe to a topic?
NOTE: in future I need to configure also similar "bridge" configuration for other AMQP brokers different from ActiveMQ Classic

I don't think there is a way to make this work currently as the Artemis broker connection sender and receiver bits are very simple and don't convey enough information to the remote AMQP connection for it to tell what type of destination the link is attempting to connect to.  By default ActiveMQ 5 would be treating the non-prefixed destinations as a Queue and attempt to create a local Queue.
The connection sender and receiver don't use the prefixing on the configure address match values as you are already telling it via the 'address-match' setting that it is matching on an address so adding a 'topic://' makes little sense.  It might be possible to enhance the broker connection implementations for sender and receiver to add source or target capabilities to the outgoing link to inform the remote what type of receiver or sender is being created but currently that is not an available option.  From memory I think ActiveMQ 5 uses an even more basic AMQP sender and receiver detection matcher so the broker connection types might even need additional configuration for the source or target address name as you might need to prefix those values to send to ActiveMQ 5 for it to properly attach to the right destination type.
I'd generally advise to use something like Apache Camel to build a route for moving messages between to brokers as you could use native clients and configure them more appropriately for the servers they are connecting to. And the Camel route would provide error handling and logging features.

Ok, in the past I already used the Apache Camel solution (with AMQP component based on QPid client) for bridging purposes but I observed poor performance and some problems with high message throughput.

Regarding brpker-connections, just to test the feature, I tried to configure one instance of Artemis to connect to another Artemis instance, using receiver config. Connection is establish but I have not seen messages pass from the first to the second broker.

That sounds like a different question as your original is about bridging from ActiveMQ 5.  You'd need to ask a new question and provide configuration and debug
